# Assign multiple values from variable in SCSS

Tags: sass

I've variable named `classes` where each key has style values

```css
   $classes : (
     class1: (
       font-size: 15px,
       color: blue
     ),
     class2: (
      font-size: 20px,
      font-weight: 600,
      background-color: red
     )
    )
```

I'm writing `@each` rule in `scss` like below.

```css
    @each $key, $value in $classes {
      .#{$label} {
        // How to assign values here
      }
    }
```

I'm able to get `class` name but unable to add all values here. Any idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of above problem.
We can't assign `key - value` pair directly in scss.

Here we need to apply `@each` loop till the end

```
@each $key, $value in $classes {
      .#{$label} {
         @each $key1, $value1 in $value {
          .#{$key1}: $value1
         }
      }
    }
```